# Xcode - How Would You Center These Buttons In The Middle Of The Screen

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm working on a small app where I came across the part I hate most in an app.Constraints and Auto Layout.... I was trying to make six buttons stay in the middle of the screen like in the image below.[image]

But Let's just say when I tried to add my own Constraints the button well looked like this
[image]
How would I got about making the scene look like my first image.

Comment: Looks like perhaps the constraints aren't set up the way you expect them to be -- maybe some swapped first and second elements? Try clearing all your constraints, then pinning the right buttons' leading edge to the centre, and the left buttons' trailing edge to the center.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. One way would be to use three horizontal `UIStackView`s and then embed these and the main button in one vertical `UIStackView`. Set the appropriate `spacing` and `alignment` (`Fill Equally` probably). Then centre the vertical `UIStackView` (if that's the requirement - hard to tell from just screenshots). `Autolayout` is not hard, it just requires you to logically describe your interface. There are many free WWDC videos and internet tutorials that explain all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a spacer view between the buttons with no margin or padding between those three items, and create equal width constraints on the buttons and spacers such that

```
[BUTTON1][SPACER][BUTTON2]
```

Give Button1 a equal width constraint that is a 0.4 multiplier of the title button, then give the spacer one with 0.2, and button2 one with 0.4

This would make the set of three buttons span the same total width as the title button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 9.0 and greater, `UIStackView` would be best for this situation. If you still need to support iOS 8, you can try using [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView), or use a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to like using "spacer" views.  I'd add 3 long vertical hidden views: one pinned to the left/top/bottom of the super view and the left side of your buttons; one pinned to the right/top/bottom of the super view and the right side of your buttons; and one centered horizontally, pinned to top/bottom of the view, and pinned to the inside edges of your six buttons.  Then select all three spacer views and make them be equal widths.

Comment: I fixed it using blank images and centering the images and putting the button in there.Not the best way to do it but it worked.